# Already defined member called 'Search' with the same parameter types

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting a confusing error and I'm not quite sure why. Usually this kind of error pops up when you have two ActionResults and forget `[HttpPost]` on one of them. But as you can see, I *have* `[HttpPost]` there, so what could be causing this problem?

Error: `Type 'PersonalWebsite.Controllers.BlogController' already defines a member called 'Search' with the same parameter types Controllers\BlogController.cs`

and the code:

```
//
// GET: /Blog/Search

public virtual ActionResult Search()
{
    return RedirectToAction(MVC.Blog.Index());
}

//
// POST: /Blog/Search

[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public virtual ActionResult Search(SearchViewModel model)
{
    // irrelevant code snipped

    return View(model);
}
```

There are no other `Search()` methods defined in this controller. It's bizarre.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about it's base class?

Comment: `public partial class BlogController : Controller` - generic base class

Comment: Can you post the entire controller? Also _when_ do you get the error you mentioned?

Comment: Entire controller here, but it doesn't have the GET method in this version - I just realise that going to /blog/search without a POST gave a 404. https://github.com/Imdsm/PersonalWebsite/blob/master/PersonalWebsite/Controllers/BlogController.cs#L82

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Search` method is already defined in another `partial`.

See here: https://github.com/Imdsm/PersonalWebsite/blob/master/PersonalWebsite/BlogController.generated.cs

```
[NonAction]
[GeneratedCode("T4MVC", "2.0"), DebuggerNonUserCode]
public virtual System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Search()
```

Comment: That would make sense. Didn't think to look in the T4MVC. Just needed to run T4MVC again. I thought I'd installed [Chirpy](https://chirpy.codeplex.com/downloads/get/212976) to do this for me. Thanks haim770!

Comment: As a side note for future searchers, Chirpy doesn't seem to be the best option, but I did find something on NuGet called AutoT4MVC, found here: https://github.com/bennor/AutoT4MVC

Answer (score 2):

You could create an alias for your method via:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [ActionName("Search")]
    public virtual ActionResult SearchByPost(SearchViewModel model)
    {
        // irrelevant code snipped

        return View(model);
    }
```